# Unable to install OS on ProBook 430 G3 driver required

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, windows-installation, usb-3

I'm getting a message 'Load Driver'
'A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.'

I've read that it's due to Windows 7 not having USB 3.0 drivers, and the 'fix' is to plug the drive into a USB 2.0 port. I'm using the USB 2.0 port and no joy, so assuming it's using the same chipset at the USB 3.0 ports.

Thanks in advance